# Keyword for packed method arguments in method with fixed signature

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find the right keywords to find a related question.

If I have a method `MethodA` that takes an arbitrary number of parameters, is it possible, when calling it from another method `MethodB` which does not accept arbitrary amounts of parameters, to conveniently "pack" together and forward parameters from `MethodB` to `MethodA`?

This is for pure convenience, wondering if a special keyword exists or shorthand to do this. While I don't expect such a feature to exist without it using verbose reflection, I wouldn't be surprised if it did, hence my question.

Here's an example:

```
public void MethodA(params object[] args)
{
    // Stuff
}

public void MethodB(int longNameNumber1, string longNameWord1, string evenLongerNameWord2)
{
    MethodA(packedArgs); // Equivalent to MethodA(longNameNumber1, longNameWord1, evenLongerNameWord2);
    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: Nope, there's no such thing.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: So you kind of pointed out to that correctly - you can use Reflection to do it at runtime. Another alternative would be to use AOP and weaving (e.g. using `Fody`) to generate this for you at compile time, or a Roslyn analyser to generate something prior to.

There are no built-in language constructs to achieve what you want, though.